# CKEditor 4 format_tags

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to change my format_tags list in ckeditor so that it doesn't have the preformatted and address in the list but if I try putting:

```
CKEDITOR.config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;';
```

into my config.js, nothing happens - the list stays the same.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it turns out you need to add it to the editorConfig:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.format_tags = 'p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;div';
};
```

Comment: This happens, because you set `CKEDITOR.config.format_tags` but then when `format` plugin is loaded it overwrites your configuration. That's why there's `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` function.

Comment: How can I add an extra tag "p class =Intro" in the editor ??

Comment: @pr https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_howtos_styles.html#how-do-i-add-custom-styles-based-on-css-classes

Answer (score 0):

if you doesn't want use the file `config.js` (for whatever reason) you can do also this:

```
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'idofyourtextarea', {
    language: 'your_language', //for example 'es'
    height: 200,
    width: 300,
    format_tags: 'h1;h2;h3;h4;div' // <---here set the format tag
});
```